# Выводить по две плитки при горизонтальном положении

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Использую Bootstrap 3.3.7.

Есть такие блоки:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 item">
  ****
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 item">
  ****
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 item">
  ****
</div>
```

На большом экране вывожу в ряд по три плитки, на меньшем тоже три, на маленьком по 2, на очень маленьком по одной.

Если зайти с iPhone (6), в вертикальном положении выводит по одной плитке как и нужно. Если повернуть телефон горизонтально - все равно выводит по одной плитке в ряд, то есть все еще действует .xs , но ведь места достаточно для двух плиток в ряд.

Почему так случается и как это исправить?

Comment: Оказалось не только на 6, но и на 5. На других нет возможности проверить. Исправить => медиа-запросы.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что 768px вроде как они срабатывают, а лучше пишите на flex, там все автоматически подстроится и если хватит место для второго то и второй влезит, хватит писать ГавноКОД пожалуйста, Задайте 1 класс, зачем 100500 плодить, после вас потом хрен верстку поймешь, а клиенту не объяснишь что предыдущий верстальщик не был с руками.
P.S Простите.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-item {
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
  1
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
  2
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
  3
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
  4
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
  5
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
  6
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
  7
  </div>
</div>
```